# Applying 'less than' filter on list of images in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am writing a simple GEE code to loop a list of numbers and filter a raster image (DEM) for values less than the numbers in the list.

```
var aec = function(n){
  var ii = ee.Image(n)    // casting the number to image before filtering but didn't work
  var DEM141 = DEM.lte(ii)

  var DEM141Count = DEM141.reduceRegion({
    geometry: ROI,
    scale: 30,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
  })
  return DEM141Count
}

var elevs = ee.List.sequence(140,150,1);
var areas = elevs.map(aec)
print(areas)
```

However, I keep getting this error:
`Image.lte, argument 'image2': Invalid type. Expected: Image<unknown bands>. Actual: Float.`

The GEE code link is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e55360bc82695f930d64ee70a415dc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the threshold image from `ee.Image.constant()` method.

```js
var aec = function(n){
  var ii = ee.Image.constant(n)
  var DEM141 = DEM.lte(ii)

  var DEM141Count = DEM141.reduceRegion({
    geometry: ROI,
    scale: 30,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
  })
  return DEM141Count
}
```